# Grails GORM: Mapping tree legacy table

Tags: grails, tree, grails-orm, one-to-many, legacy

I'm currently trying to map a legacy (mysql) table with the following 3 relevant fields:

```
id -> Long
parentId -> Long
title -> String
```

`id` and `parentId` describe the tree-structure. What I need is a method to search all nodes under a given one for a certain title and retrieve that node's `id`. I am new to Grails and can't get my head around mapping that one-to-many relationship based on an existing table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To map the class, try something like this:

```
class Foo {

    String title
    Foo parent

    static mapping = {
        parent column: 'parentId'
    }
}
```

You don't need to specify the `id` as a `Long` because that is the default. You will, however, need to specify the `id` if it has a column name other than `id`.

As far as the parent object goes, you will need to map it by the foreign key column's name.